Grub config option GRUB_DEFAULT is ignored
I installed debian 12 as a virtual machine and accidentally installed xen-tools (which you don't need inside a guest system). After removing xen-tools my grub menu still lists the xen entry which is the second and also the default boot option.
I tried to change the option GRUB_DEFAULT=0 in /etc/default/grub and update-grub but after reboot nothing changed, default entry is still the second one!
What am I missing?
grub-mkconfig output
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=de_DE
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/desktop-base/emerald-theme/grub/grub-4x3.png; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=black/white
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
    echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-23-amd64-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-23-amd64-recovery-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-22-amd64-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64 root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.1.0-22-amd64-recovery-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64 root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-simple-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
    echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64 ...'
        if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
            xen_rm_opts=
        else
            xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
        fi
    multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.gz placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
    echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
    module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux (with Xen hypervisor)' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
    submenu 'Xen hypervisor, version 4.17-amd64' $menuentry_id_option 'xen-hypervisor-4.17-amd64-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64 and Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-23-amd64-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64 ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.gz placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64 and Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-23-amd64-recovery-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64 ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.gz placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64 and Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-22-amd64-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64 ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.gz placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64 and Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-22-amd64-recovery-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64 ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.gz placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
        }
    }
    submenu 'Xen hypervisor, version 4.17-amd64.efi' $menuentry_id_option 'xen-hypervisor-4.17-amd64.efi-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64.efi and Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-23-amd64-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64.efi ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.efi placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64.efi and Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-23-amd64-recovery-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64.efi ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.efi placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-23-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-23-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64.efi and Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-22-amd64-advanced-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64.efi ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.efi placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro  quiet
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.17-amd64.efi and Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-6.1.0-22-amd64-recovery-a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.17-amd64.efi ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /boot/xen-4.17-amd64.efi placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 6.1.0-22-amd64 ...'
            module2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a4bf4623-189d-481d-bb81-11ed0dae800d ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-22-amd64
        }
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###


Do you have residual configs left? apt search xen |grep residual. If yes, remove them with apt purge.

No. All xen configs were removed. But that is not the problem. The problem is, that GRUB_DEFAULT=0 has no effect. From my understandig, GRUB_DEFAULT allows to specify the default boot entry.

It should, yes. But I'd focus on removing the void entries nevertheless. Even if you get it working on the correct entry now, the next time your kernel gets updated the order could change and you need to do modifications again.
